# bootstrap datetimepicker not working within modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap `datetimepicker`. Normally it is working. But in the modal pop up, it is not working. What could be the problem.

JS:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.inspection')
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl)
    .controller('scheduleModalCtrl', scheduleModalCtrl);

mainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$modal'];

function mainCtrl($scope, $state, $modal) {

 $scope.schedule_modal = function() {
   var modalView = $modal.open({
   templateUrl:'schedule_modal.html',
   backdrop: 'static',
   controller: 'scheduleModalCtrl',
   windowClass: 'modal-dialog-schedule'
 });
}

scheduleModalCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];
function scheduleModalCtrl($scope, $modalInstance) {
 $('#date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
 });
}
})();
```

schedule_modal.html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
 <label for="insp-date" class="label-style">Date</label>
 <div class='input-group date' id='date'>
  <input type='text' class="input-style" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

route.config.js :

```
.state('app.main', {
 url: '/manageinspection',
 title: 'Manage Inspection Page',
 controller: 'mainCtrl',
 templateUrl:   helper.basepath('pages/main/main.html'),
 resolve: helper.resolveFor('bootstrap','moment','bootstrapDateTimePicker')
})
```

I have include `moment.js` and `bootstrapDateTimePicker` constants in `lazyload` and in the `route.config resolve`. The `datetimepicker` is opening in `mainCtrl(main page)`. It is not working in modal pop up, that is in `scheduleModalCtrl`.

I found several solutions, but they are all for `ui-bootstarp datepicker` but not for `datetimepicker`

Comment: This should be problem with z-index

Comment: No, the widget is not even getting attached in the DOM

Comment: May be timing issue. The DOM is created after $('#date').datetimepicker({}) is called. Try printing $('#date') just before it is invoked?

Comment: Gave something like $timeout(function(){$('#date').datetimepicker();}); . Also tried setTimeout for 5, both are not working. I think it's something to do with the scope..! But not sure how to resolve it

Comment: Did you yry printing $('#date') just before $('#date').datetimepicker() is invoked?

Comment: I am not able to console.log in the modal...! :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about [angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)?

If you are, I had the same problem. The datepicker (using dropdown) never works fine on modal (at least bootstrap's modal).

My palliative solution, to maintain the consistency is "disable" the dropdown event on click in the input field. To execute the dropdown event, I'm using a 'input-group-addon' in this way:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/NandoMB/tLpbzkfj/27/embedded/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can I get this link up again?